# Display events on Calendar by time

Tags: entities, datetime

I am trying to display the events on a calendar, and have setup the calendar module with the date/ time. I am able to get the events to display on the calendar but they all are showing up as all day events. I have adjusted the formatting of the date/ time every way I can think of.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Had a configuration issues with Dates